# How do I declare a variable with a type from another package in Go?

Tags: types, go

For example:

```
package foo

import (
    "appengine/blobstore"
)

func main() {
    var blob blobstore.BlobInfo
    ...
}
```

Gives me this error:
undefined: BlobInfo

Is there a way for me to be able to create this struct without having to copy the code over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `blobstore.BlobInfo` is a type then declare a variable of that type in another package like:

```
var blob blobstore.BlobInfo
```

The syntax

```
var foo = bar.Qux
```

attempts to create var `foo` and initialize it by assigning it the *value* of `bar.Qux` while inferring `bar.Qux`'s *type*.

EDIT:

To declare a variable of type T

```
var v T
```

T can come from other package. For example

```
import "foo/bar"
import baz "qux"
import . "whatever"

var v1 bar.T
var v2 baz.T
var v3 T // whatever.T
```

If this doesn't work for you then some of the possible problems are:

- Package `blobstore` is not instaled.
- Package `blobstore` is not found in your GOPATH using the import path shown in the OP.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did mean var blob blobstore.BlobInfo. I've edited the question.